# Partial name search in "ideographic" locale

Tags: search, search-results, names

I'm building a UI that includes search by person's name, for locales where majority of names are spelt with kanji or hànzì.

Search in Latin script often features live partial search and sometimes approximate search. I suspect that's due to names being long sequences of simple characters.

I wonder if same expectation holds for users in the locales where names are expressed as short sequences of complex characters.

Do the Japanese users expect partial match from phonetic typing before a character is formed? Do the Chinese users?

Is there an equivalent UI/UX paradigm in these locales?

Answer (score 1):

**Three components of Japanese writing system are hiragana, katakana and kanji.**

As per my understanding, it depends on the sound of the characters and not the letters itself. Take for example the below scenario. If a user tries to search Japanese character て which is te

て
te

he can have any of the below results even if the list writing system doesnot contain it. Refer the screenshot.[image]

hiragana てんき
katakana テンキ
kanji 天気

```
 tennki
```